# Check whether a column is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I need to retrieve columns of a row that one of its data types is empty.
Extra VARCHAR
Extra has nothing in it

Show those with empty extra column

```
  Select * FROM Items WHERE Extra ?????
```

What should be the condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether it is null or empty string.

```
 Select * FROM Items WHERE Extra IS NULL OR Extra = ''
```

Comment: Here's a good habit to get into...  Put all ORs in parens.  The first time you try to edit a `WHERE` clause with an `OR`, you'll appreciate them...

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from items where Isnull(extra,'')=''
```

Answer (score 1):

If empty means "" or empty string then:

```
select * from items where extra="";
```

The length of empty string is zero/0 .

If empty means NULL then:

```
select * from items where extra is NULL;
```

The length of NULL is NULL.

If you want to read more, you can read these:

- [MySQL: NULL vs ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106258/mysql-null-vs)
- [MySQL, better to insert NULL or empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
FROM Items 
WHERE Extra IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you by empty mean NULL...

```
Select * FROM Items WHERE Extra IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Select empty `varchar` fields, with either an empty string or NULL in it:

```
SELECT * FROM `Items` WHERE `Extra` < 1;
```

Comment: If 'extra' is null, your express will return null, and no row will be returned.  Plus it's typecasting everything, and is hard to read.