# Insert NULL or Empty in a Database?

Tags: mysql, database, storage

There is a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string) in which is discussed the impacts of inserting a NULL value or an empty value. However, the answers involved both programming and query impacts, and the storage system was not mentioned.

Do the DBMSs (more specifically MySQL and PostgreSQL) make some assumptions whether a value is null or is empty? What is the impact on storage and efficiency?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: NULL vs ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106258/mysql-null-vs)

Comment: Unless you can measure it, forget about it. Seriously, we have *terabyte* sized hard drives today. The primary reason for `NULL` is to separate between "empty" and "undefined", nothing more.

Comment: True, Eric, [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12706491/3381662) is the answer I was looking for.