# Is there any speed difference in checking for field = '' vs field IS NULL?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `apps` WHERE dev_name = '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Right now I'm checking for a blank `dev_name` but would it be faster if I set the default value to `NULL` and used `NULL` in the SELECT instead?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106258/mysql-null-vs

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd Which answer talks about speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed is not the reason for picking one versus the other.  In your limited example, `x = ''` and `x IS NULL` will probably preform identical speed.

What should be considered in `NULL` versus `''` (or `0`) is other forms of testing, and what the meaning of the column is.

For example, if there are "no fees", should the `fee` column be `0` or `NULL`?  `NULL` seems to imply "no fees".  However, `WHERE fee < 100` is less clumsy than `WHERE fee IS NULL OR fee < 100`, so I would vote for `0`.

`COUNT(dev_name)` will count `''`, but not `NULL`.  This could be the deciding factor.

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would say this is a micro-optimization and it's better to model your queries and table structure to something that feels semantically correct.

As this is a generic question, just try to read up on other questions here on SO and decide for yourself. It's hard to say if your specific setup will have a performance win by any of the options. If you want to know for sure, try to make a benchmark for yourself, that's also fun to do :)