# Difference between (NULL) and empty in mysql column values

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-null

I am working in a company where we use Spring -Hibernate and mysql database at backend.

There is a table **tc_wallet**
In this table i have an column **tips_type** which has values

1. Collection,Payable
2. `''`  (empty)
3. `NULL` --> No value has been initialized

Now when i fire a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tc_wallet` 
WHERE 
    login_id = 'gaurav.wakharkar' 
    AND `delete_flag` = 'F' 
    AND `tips_type` != 'Collection'
```

I get results which has column value as '' (empty).

```
Login_id            tips_type   
gaurav.wakharkar                 
gaurav.wakharkar         
gaurav.wakharkar
```

But even (NULL) is != 'Collection' should satisfy the above condition.
So according to me the result should have been .

```
Login_id            tips_type   
gaurav.wakharkar                 
gaurav.wakharkar         
gaurav.wakharkar       
gaurav.wakharkar    (NULL)   
gaurav.wakharkar    (NULL)
```

Is there some issue while checking/comparing values with (NULL) ?
Does it behave differently ?

Comment: maybe this will help to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106258/mysql-null-vs

Comment: Typing `mysql null empty string` into any search engine would have answered that for you.

Comment: You might want to check this: [three valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check for nullness, you want to use `IS NULL`. Comparing `NULL` to something else with the equality operator (or the inequality operator) is always false.

Consider:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tc_wallet` 
WHERE 
    login_id = 'gaurav.wakharkar' 
    AND `delete_flag` = 'F' 
    AND (`tips_type` IS NULL OR `tips_type` != 'Collection')
```

Comment: You should mention three-valued logic here to make the answer complete. Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

change your query to

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `tc_wallet` 
WHERE login_id = 'gaurav.wakharkar' 
  AND `delete_flag` = 'F' 
  AND (`tips_type` != 'Collection' or `tips_type` is null)
```