# Defining a variable with multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to lookup a variable that matches the two given criteria. Please see script below:

```
Dim usr As String
Dim pafa As String
usr = DLookup("UserID", "tt_CurrentUser")
pafa = DLookup("PassFail", "dbo_TestDetail", [WHERE "dbo_TestDetail.TestIndex" = " & Me!JobLU & " And "dbo_TestDetail.SN" = " & Me!SN & "])
```

As shown, pafa is the variable I am having issues with.

> Run-time error '2465' pops up with a message reading "Manufacturing Test Manager can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression".

When I hit Debug, line 4 is highlighted. " & Me!JobLU & " and " & Me!JobLU & " are both the correct values when I hover my mouse over the text.

What am I doing wrong when defining these two criteria?

Also, pafa is going to equal either "Fail" or Null.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL server and not the language your code is written in?

Comment: You should check DLookup sintaxis https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use WHERE and the brackets? The quotations are also wrong. When doing concatenation you need to distinguish literal string and identifiers that need to be evaluated. Try

```
"dbo_TestDetail.TestIndex = " & Me!JobLU & " And dbo_TestDetail.SN = " & Me!SN
```

Hovering the mouse over expressions and see the correct evaluation doesn't mean that an outer expression is written correctly.

Comment: It's giving a run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630961/null-values-for-variables-in-vba) for a possible change of your data type.